# Unable to get through to the custom form using hook_menu page callback?

Tags: 7, forms, routes

Inside the hook_menu I have ,

```
$items['abc/def/%node'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('heart_form',2),
    'access arguments' => array('modify  heart status'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

Inside my custom form I have the foll code..

```
function heart_form(&$form_state, $node) {
   $form['notes'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Please give an explanation'),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Save'));

  return $form;
}
```

But when I try to go on the link , `www.example.com/abc/def/18` I get a page not found message
What is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sanity checks first:

- Make sure you're returning `$items` from `hook_menu()`
- Make sure you've cleared the caches since making changes to code in `hook_menu()`
- You probably don't mean to have two spaces between the first two words in your permission string.
- Make sure there's a node with an ID of 18 in the system; if not the `%node` load argument will fail and you'll get a 404.

The only other problem (but not one that would causes a 404) is the signature for your form function; it should be

```
function heart_form($form, &$form_state, $node) {
```

Comment: yes I am returning $items

Comment: What about the other 3 things?

Comment: i will update about the rest soon..

Comment: cleared the caches..Now its working thnx a lot

Comment: No worries, it's the Drupal golden rule - if something doesn't work, clear the cache before trying anything else!